# What would be the right word for "meme" in the original, Dawkinsian sense?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Meme" coined by Dawkins, has an original sense that's very useful for describing units of culture:

> A meme acts as a unit for carrying cultural ideas, symbols, or practices, that can be transmitted from one mind to another through writing, speech, gestures, rituals, or other imitable phenomena with a mimicked theme. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme)

But now, it seems that the meaning of the word has been co-opted to specifically describe jokes on twitter and instagram that follow a specific format.

"Trend" seems to be the closest, but I don't think it really captures the original sense of "meme".

[1. Meme (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme)

Comment: Is it possible to argue with your premise? Like many words, "meme" has accreted an additional, related or figurative meaning, but that doesn't mean it's been co-opted. In an anthropological context, I expect you could use "meme" in its original sense with no explanation. Unless you were specifically writing an anthropological paper about Internet memes, in which case you would quite naturally let your reader know which sense you were using in context.

Comment: I agree with MetaEd. I think using "meme" in the sense that you refer to and without additional explanation would be just fine. I don't think its meaning has been co-opted either. Actually, that is the meaning I would first think of if someone asked me what that word meant.

Comment: The formal field of study is still called memetics.

Comment: ritual, icon, style, practice, symbol, convention, trait, etc

Comment: Dawkins coined the word precisely because there wasn't a term that described the concept. And there still isn't, because people who study cultural evolution presumably use his word, despite the way the Internet has adopted it.

Comment: _Tradition_ (meaning: a belief, statement, custom, etc., handed down from generation to generation) comes close but still not an exact synonym. I agree with the other comments also. You can consider _cultural concept_ also in the right context.

Comment: As a parallel with 'junk DNA' perhaps the laughing dogs, singing cats and skateboarding gerbils could be described as **junk memes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Meme*. As with many words a particular sense can so eclipse another, often earlier, sense as to cause confusion, but the best one can do is to explain how one is using the term and carry on, especially since neither the source *mimeme* (from which *meme* is a shortening deliberately seeking to chime with *gene*) nor the similar *mneme* have gained currency.

If really necessary one could use *memetic unit*.